# Best way to convert an MD5 to decimal in Golang?

Tags: go

In Python I can do

```
int(hashlib.md5('hello world').hexdigest(), 16)
```

which results in

```
125893641179230474042701625388361764291L
```

What's the equivalent in Golang to take an MD5 string and get the decimal representation?

Comment: The question is strange.  What does it mean to interpret an md5 to a single decimal?  An MD5 is a 128-bit (16 byte) hash.  Those bytes are not intended to be interpreted as a single integer.

Comment: @dyoo An MD5 hash is binary (base2), usually encoded to hex (base16), and OP wants to convert it to decimal (base10). No, it's not intended to be used for math, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: There's *possible*, and then there's *useful*.  If the original questioner is concerned about space, then they can just hold onto the byte-string of 16 bytes (not the hexdigest, but the actual bytes) and do straightforward equality comparisons.  It's the coersion to big-integer representation that seems odd to me: that indicates that they're trying to do something... arithmetic?  So more context into what future operations they plan to do with the integer value would be very helpful; as it is, without context, the original question is trying to do something weird.

Comment: @dyoo yes, Your are right, it's very useful, when doing a map reduce or load banlance consistant hasing algorithm, there's needs to create a hashring using md5 or other hash algorithm. This powers the distributed system like memcache, redis, map-reduce, and cdn load-banlancer and even on the amazon dynamo kv database in the open system, almost everyone use it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [math/big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/).

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    bi := big.NewInt(0)
    h := md5.New()
    h.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    hexstr := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    bi.SetString(hexstr, 16)
    fmt.Println(bi.String())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/3h521Ao1UY

Comment: Minor optimization, you don't actually need to encode it to hex, you can use `bi.SetBytes` directly : http://play.golang.org/p/hHSnNPWUP8

Comment: @OneOfOne That's true if you're starting with the `[]byte` value, the question references an MD5 string so OP may be starting with the hex.